# g++ ignores overwritten virtual function

Tags: c++, virtual

I have two classes like this (simplified and renamed):

```
class Base
{
 public:
  virtual void operator()( ) { cout << "Base\n";}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
 public:
  void operator()( ) { cout << "Derived\n"; }
};

void doSomething( Base obj )
{
  obj( );
}

int main( )
{
  list<Base> bList;
  Derived d1, d2, d3;
  bList.push_back( d1 );
  bList.push_back( d2 );
  bList.push_back( d3 );

  for( list<Base>::iterator it = bList.begin(); it != bList.end(); it++ )
    {
      doSomething( *it );
    }
  return 0;
}
```

When I run this, I get:

```
Base
Base
Base
```

i.e. the Base::operator() is called. Obviously this is not what I want to happen.
I tried changing doSomething to

```
void doSomething( Base& obj )
```

but this only works if called directly with a Derived object and not with one from the list. And references can't be stored in a list.
Is there any way how I can make doSomething "see" that it has to call a derived class' function (without having to resort to pointers)?

Edit: Problem is pointed out, for other people who might run into this here is a link:
[What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)

Comment: Use a pointer to `Base` and check if you can `dynamic_cast` it to `Derived`.

Comment: @chris: That is half wrong. The suggestion to use a pointer is good, the suggestion to use `dynamic_cast` is not. There is no need to cast, the virtual dispatch mechanism will pick the correct override.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, ah, thanks. I was thinking of something else then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't that the compiler doesn't "see" that it needs to call a function in a derived class, the problem is that you are only storing the base class in your container `list<Base>`. This results in what is commonly called object slicing. When the compiler copies your `Derived` objects into the container that can only hold `Base` objects, it can only copy the base portion of the object and "slices" off the part that makes it a `Derived` object.

In order to make use of polymorphism with containers that follow value semantics (ie, assume that you store the actual object in them and not a form of reference to an object), you need store a pointer to said object. I would advise against storing raw pointers in a standard library container as it introduces additional lifecycle management issues - you'd have to control the lifetimes of the pointed-to objects from outside the container, which tends to be a really bad idea and usually either leads to memory leaks or dangling pointers, if not both.

My recommendation would be that if you can use boost, use one of the `ptr_container` template classes that were explicitly designed for this purpose. If you can't and you're on a modern enough compiler, you can use a `std::list<std::shared_ptr<Base> > >` and rely on the `shared_ptr`to manage the objects' lifecycles.

Comment: in C++11 he can use `std::unique_ptr<Base>` if no sharing is required. It is more efficient that managing reference counting with only one subject.

Answer (score 7):

The following:

```
list<Base> bList;
Derived d1, d2, d3;
bList.push_back( d1 );
bList.push_back( d2 );
bList.push_back( d3 );
```

**slices** your objects. They are no longer of type `Derived`, but `Base`. You need to use pointers or smart pointers in your container for the expected behavior.

Read up on object slicing.

Comment: **And** fix the `doSomething` function to avoid slicing there

Comment: Thanks, now I see why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above lead me to the ultimate solution.  The short answer is, "No.  You must use a list of pointers."  Here's what I came up with...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <list>

class Base
{
    public:
        virtual void foo()
        {
            std::cout << "Base::foo" << std::endl;
        }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        void foo()
        {
            std::cout << "Derived::foo" << std::endl;
            Base::foo();
        }
};

int main()
{
    std::list<std::shared_ptr<Base>> bases;
    auto p = std::make_shared<Derived>();
    bases.push_back(p);

    for (std::list<std::shared_ptr<Base>>::iterator i = bases.begin(); i != bases.end(); i++)
    {
        (*i)->foo();
    }

    return 0;
}
```